# Как открыть настройки приложения из своего приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет столкнулся с необходимостью открыть настройки приложения из самого приложения не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Используй для этого:

`new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)`